# No speakers after resume

Tags: sound, suspend, speakers, toshiba

when I close my laptop and I reopen it, the internal speakers stop working. Headphones and HDMI work though.
 If I reboot, it works again.

I tried to modify

> /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf

by adding one at a time :
options snd-hda-intel probe_mask=0x01
options snd-hda-intel model=auto
options snd-hda-intel model=thinkpad
options snd-hda-intel model=ideapad
options snd-hda-intel model=generic

None of them worked.

I also tried

```
sudo alsa force-reload

pulseaudio -k
```

I tried reinstalling pulseaudio, tried installing OSS4 instead of Alsa too with no result

Here is the result of `bash alsa-info.sh`

Before
http://alsa-project.org/db/?f=a7cfba1c07f7eca10ef14dbb75332d4b7eb9bcb2
After resume
http://alsa-project.org/db/?f=9849b95672ff80c2d4313993dcb9df93c24dc68d
I tried on Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04 with fresh install
Also tried on Live session of Fedora 32, Manjaro 20.1

```
System:
  Kernel: 5.4.0-47-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 9.3.0 
  Desktop: Gnome 3.36.4 Distro: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
Machine:
  Type: N/A System: TOSHIBA product: PORTEGE Z20t-C v: PT16BE-007007FR 
  serial: <filter> 
  Mobo: TOSHIBA model: PORTEGE Z20t-C v: Version A0 serial: <filter> 
  UEFI: TOSHIBA v: Version 2.10 date: 12/08/2015 
Battery:
  ID-1: BAT1 charge: 30.1 Wh condition: 30.1/36.0 Wh (84%) 
  model: G71C000JQ210 status: Discharging 
  ID-2: BAT2 charge: 22.1 Wh condition: 27.8/36.0 Wh (77%) 
  model: G71C000JQ210 status: Discharging 
CPU:
  Topology: Dual Core model: Intel Core m7-6Y75 bits: 64 type: MT MCP 
  arch: Skylake rev: 3 L2 cache: 4096 KiB 
  flags: avx avx2 lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx 
  bogomips: 11999 
  Speed: 500 MHz min/max: 400/3100 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 500 2: 500 
  3: 500 4: 500 
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel HD Graphics 515 vendor: Toshiba driver: i915 v: kernel 
  bus ID: 00:02.0 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.8 driver: i915 resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel HD Graphics 515 (SKL GT2) v: 4.6 Mesa 20.0.8 
  direct render: Yes 
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio vendor: Toshiba 
  driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus ID: 00:1f.3 
  Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.4.0-47-generic 
Network:
  Device-1: Intel Ethernet I219-LM vendor: Toshiba driver: e1000e v: 3.2.6-k 
  port: efa0 bus ID: 00:1f.6 
  IF: enp0s31f6 state: down mac: <filter> 
  Device-2: Intel Wireless 8260 driver: iwlwifi v: kernel port: efa0 
  bus ID: 02:00.0 
  IF: wlp2s0 state: up mac: <filter> 
  IF-ID-1: wwan0 state: down mac: <filter> 
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 238.47 GiB used: 13.96 GiB (5.9%) 
  ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Samsung model: MZNLN256HCHP-00000 size: 238.47 GiB 
  temp: 36 C 
  Message: No Optical or Floppy data was found. 
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 18.96 GiB used: 8.17 GiB (43.1%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda6 
  ID-2: /boot size: 1.35 GiB used: 207.5 MiB (15.1%) fs: ext2 dev: /dev/sda5 
  ID-3: /home size: 20.06 GiB used: 5.53 GiB (27.6%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda7 
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 48.5 C mobo: N/A 
  Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A 
Info:
  Processes: 271 Uptime: 14m Memory: 7.69 GiB used: 1.38 GiB (17.9%) 
  Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: 9.3.0 Shell: bash v: 5.0.17 
  inxi: 3.0.38
```